# JOIN statement with OR statement

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to figure something out with a JOIN issue where I need to use an or statement in the join.

I have 2 tables.  Table 1 has about 1000 records and table 2 has millions.

Table 1 has 2 fields (claim1, claim2) and if either of those fields match the table 2.claim field, then I need the table2.field1 and table2.field2 values inserted into a temp table.

So lets say I have these two tables

```
    table 1 claim1  claim2      table 2 claim   field1  field2
              1001    2001          1001    a1  a2
              1002    2002          1002    b1  b2
              1003    2003          1003    c1  c2
                                    2001    d1  d2
                                    2002    e1  e2
```

I am trying to get the values out of table 2 for the records in table 1 for both claim1 and claim2 fields.

So I wrote this

```
SELECT CLAIM, FIELD1, FIELD2
FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T2.CLAIM = T1.CLAIM1 
                OR T2.CLAIM = T1.CLAIM2​
```

If I just run this it runs in seconds and I get the records back.

```
SELECT CLAIM, FIELD1, FIELD2
FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T2.CLAIM = T1.CLAIM1
```

after I added the or statement I killed the query after about 15 minutes.

```
SELECT CLAIM, FIELD1, FIELD2
FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T2.CLAIM = T1.CLAIM1 
                OR T2.CLAIM = T1.CLAIM2​
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am just having a heck of a time wrapping my brain around this

Comment: You can have two separate queries and try UNION instead of using OR.

Comment: Please tag your DBMS (version included)

Comment: In would be a good option for perfomance, not as fast as two statements but faster than or.    ie T2.CLAIM in (T1.CLAIM,T1.CLAIM2)

Comment: @JGFMK: https://blog.jooq.org/2016/07/05/say-no-to-venn-diagrams-when-explaining-joins/

Comment: Perhaps do a select distinct on claim1 and claim2 into a single first temp table just naming field with alias as claim each tume Then do a select distinct into a second temp table into a second temp table., then join that to your table 2. or just do nested `in` clause with select claim from temp2 inside it

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can't say I agree - they work just fine for me in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this SQL:

```
SELECT CLAIM, FIELD1, FIELD2 FROM TABLE1 JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.CLAIM1 = TABLE2.CLAIM
UNION ALL
SELECT CLAIM, FIELD1, FIELD2 FROM TABLE1 JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.CLAIM2 = TABLE2.CLAIM
```

It should work!

But, I think there must be some more columns of your parent **TABLE1** table included in query. Because in the given example this query will work something like a filter. A filter which will ensure that all the records of **TABLE2** that are being appended in **TEMP TABLE** have at least one record in parent **TABLE1**.

And if you are managing your data with integrity then the result would be something same as it is for `SELECT * FROM TABLE2`.

Comment: SELECT * FROM TABLE2 won't work because I only want the values in table 2 if there is a record in Table1 for that claim.

Comment: I knew this would work SELECT CLAIM, FIELD1, FIELD2 FROM TABLE1 JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.CLAIM1 = TABLE2.CLAIM
UNION ALL
SELECT CLAIM, FIELD1, FIELD2 FROM TABLE1 JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.CLAIM2 = TABLE2.CLAIM, I just couldn't figure out why the or wasn't.

Comment: Dear! I'm saying that 'If you are managing your data with integrity then...'. I have not posted it as your answer. The answer is the FIRST SQL statement. If you don't got my point then just leave it and try my first SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

`OR` is a performance killer, particularly for `JOIN`s.  You can solve this problem with two `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
SELECT COALESCE(T2_1.CLAIM, T2_2.CLAIM) as CLAIM,
       COALESCE(T2_1.FIELD1, T2_2.FIELD1) as FIELD1,
       COALESCE(T2_1.FIELD2, T2_2.FIELD2) as FIELD2
FROM TABLE1 T1 LEFT JOIN
     TABLE2 T2_1
     ON T2_1.CLAIM = T1.CLAIM1 LEFT JOIN
     TABLE2 T2_2
     ON T2_2.CLAIM = T1.CLAIM2​ AND T2_1.CLAIM IS NULL
WHERE T2_1.CLAIM IS NOT NULL OR T2_2.CLAIM IS NOT NULL;
```

It is odd that you are not selecting any fields from `TABLE1`.